# jdk 1.7.25 CORBA idl build warning: Anonymous sequences and array are deprecated

Tags: java-7

My java project updated to jdk 1.7.25, over Solaris 10 environment, this is the first time seen that there is a new warning message in build log: Anonymous sequences and array are deprecated (build IDL)

problem: The main GUI(build by jdk 1.7.25) cannot been brought up

We think this maybe a problem(but not sure). The idl file is very simple:

$ cat UnsubscribeAttb.idl

//../../../proj/request/requestIfc/UnsubscribeAttb.idl

## include ../../../proj/request/requestIfc/subscribeKey.idl

module requestIfc {

struct requestIfc {

```
                bool subscribeKeys;
                sequence<subscribeKey> UnsubscribeAttbList;
              }
```

}

I put in "typedef" at the front of the last line, but build immediately gives an error complained this line, but didnot give me a specific reason. Looking for your help.

Thanks,
Curtis

Comment: Deprecation shouldn't break your code. That said, you should be able to resolve that error like this: http://www.opendds.org/faq.html#IDL_anonymous_sequence

Comment: Thanks, this warning has been solved.

Comment: But my problem is not related to this warning. Updated jdk from jdk1.7.21 to jdk1.7.25. The main GUI cannot be brought up due to SESSION_ADAPTER failed over Windows 2003 server. Not sure where is the problem. Is  the old CORBA cannot talk to java 1.7.25?

Comment: I have no idea and also this is clearly a new problem then and you should post a new question, since this one was patently wrong about the source of the problem. You should diagnose that problem further since the badly spelled error message means it's probably not a standard CORBA one but comes from your code - you need to find out what causes it.